# ng-repeat does not work as expected in bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple bootstrap popover which opens when I click on a button. I want to show a list of names in the popover body using some kind of a loop. I have the list of names in my angularjs controller. I'm using ng-repeat in the popover to build the list. ng-repeat is working well if I use it outside the popover, but it does not seem to work correctly in the popover body.

It appears to be behaving as if I have a 2-level nested ng-repeat in my code although I don't have a nested ng-repeat anywhere! Also, the popover does not seem to "pop" from the correct location (it should pop out from the button). Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance! Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aslimaye90/9hagmqss/23/)

[image: screenshot]

Here is my code for the showing the popover:

```
$scope.showPopover = function() {
      jQuery(function($) {
                $('#pop').popover({
                    html: true,
                    container: 'body',
                    title: '<b style="margin-top:5px">Some Title</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+
                            '<button type="button" id="popoverCloseButton" class="close">&times;</button>',
                    content: function() {
                        return $compile($('#popover_content').html())($scope);
                    },
                    placement: 'auto right'
                }).popover('show');

                document.getElementById("popoverCloseButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
                    $scope.destroyPopover();
                });
            });
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

I've yet to figure out WHY this is happening, so that has me intrigued, but if you inline the pop-up template and remove it from the DOM it works.

```
 $scope.showPopover = function() {
      jQuery(function($) {
                $('#pop').popover({
                    html: true,
                    container: 'body',
                    title: '<b style="margin-top:5px">Some Title</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+
                            '<button type="button" id="popoverCloseButton" class="close">&times;</button>',
                    content: function() {
                        return $compile(`<div ng-repeat="x in students">
      <input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{x.firstName}} {{x.lastName}}
        </div>`)($scope);
                    },
                    placement: 'auto right'
                }).popover('show');
```

and then remove this code from the html

```
<!-- Popover -->
    <!--<div id="popover_content" style="display:none">

        <div ng-repeat="x in students">
      <input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{x.firstName}} {{x.lastName}}
        </div>
    </div>-->
    <!-- End Popover -->
```

I'll try to dig around a little more to figure out WHY but I wonder if setting content: to something you've explicitly compiled that is actually in the DOM replicates things in some way.

**EDIT** After some digging, it seems that the "display:none" may be causing issues with the jquery .html call, which may be messing up the $compile. Still not fully convinced, but may lead you to something.

Comment: Thanks @sourdoughdetzel for the answer. The ng-repeat definitely works if I write the template as a string in the $compile(...). But that's not really the best way to do it as you've already mentioned. I hope someone can explain to us WHY this is happening.

Comment: It could be argued that it's better to store the html string in your controller rather than having it just hidden in the DOM.